# How to decrease web services response time in Liferay when using authorization?

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2, and the encryption algorithm is PBKDF2. Then, calling a json web services takes around 1.5 secs. This is clear, because is the way PBKDF2 works and implements security against brute force attacks.

The problem is, when developing an application (in Java), if I want to call several web services to obtain different data from Liferay, it takes to long time to response. For example, obtaining the organization's roles for a user takes more than 10 seconds because are needed several webservices calls.

Is there any way to speed up this procedure? The idea is not to decrease security of the password encryption, but changing the strategy: i.e. only performing authentication the first time and other calls share the same session. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: For example, if I connect to liferay web services page using a navigator (localhost:8080/api/jsonws) and I have opened a session in Liferay Portal with an authorized user, I have a response in less than 0.1 secs. Probably because the authorization algorithm is avoided due to has been already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to create a specific user with SHA1 password only used for web service access, and set Liferay to allow legacy passwords. This solution decrease the security of Liferay, but until I found any solution, is the best solution I have.

The rest of users still can use PBKDF2 passwords.